# How to convert a string to a generic type?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a binary search tree, and i am having difficulty creating the main method to implement the add method.

Here is the main method so far:

```
public static <T> void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    File inFile;
    inFile = new File("inwords.txt");
    BinaryTreeNode<T> node;
    String next;
    T tNext;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(inFile);
    LinkedBinarySearchTree<T> lbst = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<T>();

    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        next = s.next();
        node = new BinaryTreeNode(next);
        lbst.addElement(next, node);
    }

    Iterator it = myTree.iteratorInOrder();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }

}
```

the compiler says that the add method needs a type T and not a string, however i thought that the whole point of generics was that any data type can be sent in

and here are the add methods: (these where prewritten)

```
public void addElement(T element) 
{
    if (!(element instanceof Comparable))
        throw new NonComparableElementException("LinkedBinarySearchTree");

    Comparable<T> comparableElement = (Comparable<T>)element;

    if (isEmpty())
        root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element);
    else 
    {
        if (comparableElement.compareTo(root.getElement()) < 0)
        {
            if (root.getLeft() == null) 
                this.getRootNode().setLeft(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element));
            else
                addElement(element, root.getLeft());
        }
        else
        {
            if (root.getRight() == null) 
                this.getRootNode().setRight(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element));
            else
                addElement(element, root.getRight());
        }
    }
    modCount++;
}


private void addElement(T element, BinaryTreeNode<T> node) 
{
    Comparable<T> comparableElement = (Comparable<T>)element;

    if (comparableElement.compareTo(node.getElement()) < 0)
    {
        if (node.getLeft() == null) 
            node.setLeft(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element));
        else
            addElement(element, node.getLeft());
    }
    else
    {
        if (node.getRight() == null) 
            node.setRight(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element));
        else
            addElement(element, node.getRight());
    }
}
```

i am not really sure why there are two add methods and what the difference is.
any help would be great.

Comment: First, your `main` method cannot be generic.

Comment: When you define the variable/instance, you specify the generic type with its actual typa `LinkedBinarySearchTree<String> lbst =`

Comment: You don't convert a type to a generic type. You provide a type argument to a parameterized type.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you can in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

You have three methods:

`main()` - to get the input from the user and

`addElement()` to insert the user input into the tree.

`addElement()` has two versions, one that starts insertion from the root node (first version) and one that starts from a specific node.

This is indeed a bit confusing, since the first version could be replaced with a simpler one:

```
public void addElement(T element) {
    if (!(element instanceof Comparable))
        throw new NonComparableElementException("LinkedBinarySearchTree");

    Comparable<T> comparableElement = (Comparable<T>)element;

    if (isEmpty()) {
        root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(element);
        modCount++;
    }
    else { 
        addElement(element, root);
    }  
}
```